# Dropping clustered PK creating clustered index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, clustered-index

I have a 99mm+ rows 800GB table (and other tables of comparable size). I want to drop the existing clustered PK (recreate as nonclustered) and create a new clustered index. This for performance tuning. 
After reading up on performance tuning/indexing I've come to the conclusion that recreating clustered index on date, Id (identity) column might be the best bet. It will re-organize table in a logical manner with less reads and IOs.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Adventure_works] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_ADV]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Adventure_works] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_ADV] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC,
[leg_id] ASC,
[category] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Adv_date_id] ON dbo.[Adventure_works](
[biz_date] asc,
[id] asc
)
```

Before the above steps I'm dropping all other non clustered indexes (NCI) as well, since that avoids rebuilding NCIs during the dropping/creating CI.
However its still taking like 1.5 hrs to complete the operation.

Is there a faster to achieve this?

Comment: No. Dropping the clustered index will turn your table into a heap, and re-creating it again will convert it back to a clustered table - so your entire data is being copied around twice - that just takes its time, and there are no shortcuts or no magic wokarounds to avoid this

Comment: Create a new table with the desired clustered index and bulk insert to it. then add the NCI and rename the tables. Assuming you have a window where you can do this maintenance without concurrent activity.

Comment: 1.5 hours *once* is not something to optimize. You're not *continuously* reorganizing your database, are you?

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: @marc_s dropping a clustered index doesn't copy your data into a heap.  It drops the non-leaf BTree pages, leaving the leaf pages to become, in place, a heap.  See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19211.dropping-a-clustered-index-will-not-reorganize-the-heap.aspx

Comment: For a large table, consider using a Clustered Columnstore with a non-clustered primary key and possibly some non-clustered indexes.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Thanks for the clarification - I had wondered for a long time why dropping a clustered index would be copying around data - didn't really make a lot of sense...... thanks for the reference!

Comment: It does mean that the NCI would be updated twice though. Once for the RID and once for the new CI key. Probably creating the new CI with DROP_EXISTING on would avoid that.